# Numpy sum function returns 1.67772e+07

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I have two big (432*136*136*46) 'numpy.ndarray' H1 and H2 which encompass altitude values corresponding to two simulations. I want to generate an array with 1 when H1 and H2 have the same altitude and 0 when they don't. Then, I want to know how many elements I selected, so I want to calculate the sum of the elements of this matrix. Here is my code :

```
H1=np.concatenate([np.around(files1[i].hrtm()[:,0:45,:,:]/h) for i in range(0,files1.__len__())])
H2=np.concatenate([np.around(files2[i].hrtm()[:,0:45,:,:]/h) for i in range(0,files2.__len__())])

diff=np.absolute(H1-H2)
diff[diff==0.]=np.float64(-1.)
diff[diff!=-1]=np.float64(0.)
diff=diff*diff

print np.sum(diff)
```

And here is my output, which is always the same and does not depend on the data:

```
1.67772e+07
```

After some research, I read that it's related to the maximum size of a float. I tried several formats, replacing np.float64 by int, float, np.float32, or nothing, and they all give the same results.

Do you have an idea of how I could do to have the real number ?

Comment: It's related to the **precision** of a single-precision float: above the value 2^24, adding 1 does not have any effect because it is absorbed.

Comment: @rth: That's a strange assertion.  `diff == 0.` will give an array containing `True`s in the positions corresponding to zeros, and `False`s elsewhere.  It'll work just as the OP intends.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Note, "if `diff` is a float array" in my comment. I missed the fact that it was converted to integer with `np.around`. Otherwise you can end up with rounding issues like checking for `2.2 * 3.0 == 6.6` which evaluates to `False` in python.

Comment: @rth: Yes, of course you have to be careful with rounding issues.  But to say that `diff == 0.` won't match zeros is simply false, even if `diff` has a floating-point type.  (Which, incidentally, it does here, since `np.around` returns something of floating-point dtype.)  `0.0 == 0.0` is `True`!

Comment: True. I was talking on the general principle: testing if `float1==float2` is just looking for trouble, and even if it might work in 95% of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of your `diff`-array is the type of `H1` and `H2`. Since you are only adding many `1`s you can convert `diff` to `bool`:

```
print diff.astype(bool).sum()
```

or much more simple

```
print (H1 == H2).sum()
```

But since floating point values are not exact, one might test for very small differences:

```
print (abs(H1 - H2) < 1e-30).sum()
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine, thank you very much, and those solutions are much more elegant.

Comment: Note that the values of `H1` and `H2` have already been rounded to the nearest integers, so using a tolerance doesn't achieve anything here.  (And if these are altitudes in feet, say, then `1e-30` is going to be way too small to be useful: the comparison will be essentially comparing for equality.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: So I overlooked the rounding, still numerical tolerances has nothing to do with physical tolerances.

Comment: The problem with using a tolerance is selecting a useful value for that tolerance.  `1e-30` is going to be hopelessly small (from a numerical point of view, not a physical one): single-precision floats have around 7 decimal digits of precision, so any two unequal floats larger than `1e-22` are going to differ by more than `1e-30`.  That makes the tolerance test equivalent to an equality test for values larger than `1e-22`.  And given that they're altitudes, I think we can safely assume that those numbers *are* larger than `1e-22`.